# Transform dataframe column with pandas date extract day minute and hour python pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

i Have a column in a dataframe like this

Date

2011-04-24

and i want to get this output with my colmun and otger colmun hour minutes and day

Date                         Hour       minutes     day

2011-04-24  00:30:00.000       0     0           sunday

there is any way to do it using pandas python

the column is of type OBJECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dates = ['2011-04-24', '2011-05-13', '2012-06-01']
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['Date'])
```

Convert the column to datetime:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Use `.strftime()` to convert to the desired time and column format, comma separated. You're going to want to check the strftime documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to extract the correct time info.

```
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S,%a'))
```

Split in to columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Date.str.split(',',2).tolist(), columns=['Date','Hour','Day'])
```